# Unable to configure threadpool task executor for asynchronous configuration

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, configuration, threadpoolexecutor

I have some large files to be downloaded from REST Calls. I found out about `StreamingResponseBody` of spring which uses asynchronous way to write directly into response `OutputStream` by spawning another thread. This has improved the performance. However, I get an error about configuring the threadpool task executor as the default `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is not good under load. I have configured the threadpool and implemented `AsyncConfigurer` to override the method `configureAsyncSupport`. Despite all this configuration I'm unable to use the threadpool , the default asyncExecutor is being used.

Tutorial followed :- https://dzone.com/articles/streaming-data-with-spring-boot-restful-web-servic

P.S. I'm not using springboot

Comment: You need to set the `TaskExecutor` using a `WebMvcConfigurer` and by implementing the `configureAsyncSupport`. What you have done is set the `TaskExecutor` for use with `@Async`. If that is what you have done, please add the code. Also I doubt it will improve performance as the way you should be doing the download is by just writing to the `OutputStream`. It might be that you are now able to handle (a bit) more concurrent requests but the download or handling of it won't be faster.

Comment: I cannot paste the code as it's behind corporate firewall. But I have used the exact same code from the above tutorial link ,except that is on spring boot and I'm using vanilla spring MVC.

Comment: Also earlier I was using bytearrayresource , which didn't write to the outputstream directly. So I guess thats the reason for performance improvement. Also can I use the  SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor for production if I'm unable to configure the threadpool. What could be the potential problems?

Comment: Just write directly to the outputstream instead of an intermediate `ByteArrayOUtputStream` or resource. Just include the `HttpServletResponse` or `OutputStream` as a method argument of your controller method and write to that directly. That will solve your issue. If you really want to do the async you really should use a proper threadpool. If you  use the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` each download will spawn a new thread, which can lead to excessive growth, memory and performance issues.